# UNIX grep with $

Tags: regex, grep

I have a quick question:

Suppose I have a file contains:

```
abc$
$
$abc
```

and then I use grep "c\$" filename, then I got abc$ only. But if I use grep "c\\$", I got abc$.

I am pretty confused, doesn't back slash already turn off the special meaning of $? So grep "c\$" filename return me the line abc$?

Really hope who can kindly give me some suggestion.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `grep 'c\$'` (single quote) to get `abc$`.

Comment: @fedorqui Thank you for your quick response. But what is the difference between double quote and single quote?

Answer (score 2):

The double quotes are throwing you off. That allows the shell to expand meta-characters. On my Linux box using single quotes only:

```
$ grep 'abc$' <<<'abc$'
$ grep 'abc\$' <<<'abc$'
$ grep 'abc\$' <<<"abc$"
abc$
$ grep 'abc$' <<<'abc$'
$ grep 'abc\\$' <<<'abc$'
$
```

Note that the only `grep` in the five commands above that found the pattern (and printed it out) was `abc\$`. If I didn't escape the `$`, it assumed I was looking for the string `abc` that was anchored to the end of the line. When I put a single backslash before the `$`, it recognized the `$` as a literal character and not as a end of line anchor.

Note that the `$` as an end of line anchor has some *intelligence*. If I put the `$` in the middle of a regular expression, it's a regular character:

```
$ grep 'a$bc' <<<'a$bc'
a$bc
$ grep 'a\$bc' <<<'a$bc'
a$bc
```

Here, it found the literal string `a$bc` whether or not i escaped the `$`.

Tried things with double quotes:

```
$ grep "abc\$" <<<'abc$'
$ grep "abc\\$" <<<'abc$'
abc$
```

The single `\` escaped the `$` as a end of line anchor. Putting two `\\` in front escaped the `$` as a non-shell meta-character *and* as a regular expression literal.

Comment: Hi David, thank you so much for that!!!! So $ only has special meaning when it is put at the end of the regexp, is it correct?

Comment: @DavidDai Officially: It depends upon the regex library you're using. The `$` has an official meaning, and it should be _quoted_ when you need a literal `$`. However, every single regular expression library I've seen allows you to use `$` in the middle of a string without backquotes. Same with the `^` which is the start of the line anchor. After all, if the `$` is not at the end, and the `^` is not at the beginning, their purpose as anchors is pretty meaningless.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your quick response. I really appreciate it. Yes, that makes sense. You are really helpful. :P

Answer (score 1):

If you're tempted to think that `$` need to be escaped, then it's not so.

From the [GNU grep manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html), you'd figure:

The meta-characters that need to be escaped while using *basic* regular expressions are `?`, `+`, `{`, `|`, `(`, and `)`.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that it may need to be escaped or placed in single quotes to prevent the *shell* from acting on it.

Comment: @nneonneo Yep, I agree with you

Comment: @devnull Thank you all the same. But I think that $ need to be escaped some times.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `fgrep` if you want to search for literal `$` and avoid escaping `$` (which means end of line):

```
fgrep 'abc$' <<< 'abc$'
```

gives this output:

```
abc$
```

**PS:** `fgrep` is same as `grep -F` and as per the `man grep`

> -F, --fixed-strings
>                 Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick response. Yes, fgrep is also a good idea though I am looking for some suggestion of grep. However, thank you all the same

Comment: You can also use `grep -f 'abc$'`

Answer (score 0):

Sign `$` has special meaning in regexp patterns as *the end of line*, so when you use double quotes

`grep "c\$"`

the string expanded as two characters `c` and `$` and `grep` thinks that it is regexp clause *c'mon, find all lines with 'c' at the end*.

In case of singe quotes, all characters treated as each one, i.e.

`grep 'c\$'`

command will have three characters `c`, `\` and `$`. So `grep` will got all those symbols at its input and therefore he gets escaped special `$` symbol, i.e. as `\$` and do what you have expected.

Comment: Thank you Rook. It is great! So when should we use single quote or double quote? Please kindly suggest. :D

Comment: @DavidDai using double or single quotes is for your preference or the code style of project restriction or just situational: e.g. if you  like to use variables in your text strings, you will have to use double quotes and if you want to use text which already has double quoted words or phrases it is better to use single qoutes rather than escaping it. If you have far-reaching plans then single qoutes will be perefered for dealing with HTML/XML markup or JSON objects which are richly double quoted inside :)